# Ordered subfields of $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, p-adic-number-theory, ordered-fields

I recently read about real ordered fields. Using real closures, I figured out that for each algebraically closed field $C$ of characteristic $0$, there exists a real closed subfield $R\subseteq C$ such that the extension is algebraic (and $[C:R]=2$). This follows very easily using real closures and Zorn's lemma.

Applying this to the field $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$, it follows that there exists an ordered subfield $R\subseteq \mathbb{Q}_p$ such that the extension is algebraic. The field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ cannot be ordered itself (as $-1$ is a sum of squares), it follows that $R\subseteq \mathbb{Q}_p$ is a strict extension. However, $\mathbb{Q}_p$ has no nontrivial endomorphisms, so the extension cannot be normal.

Are there any explicit constructions for $R$? And if the extension is finite, what would be a generator for $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: Here's a terrible construction: pick any isomorphism from $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}_p$ to $\mathbb{C}$, then consider the image of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: You’ve made (extremely) fundamental use of Axiom of Choice here, I think. You should expect that there is no explicit construction of the type you ask for. More generally speaking, it seems to me that you’re asking to do something radically unnatural. If it yields something, more power to you. But I don’t think it will.